# Black Screen after intial startup

Tags: windows-xp

and before Boot, the black screen comes up. I then keep waiting and nothing happens.

After a restart i see a Windows XP boot and then a black screen comes up. But after waiting for 10 minutes or so, i then see my login screen.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please take a look in this KB article from Microsoft: [Computer stops responding with a black screen when you start Windows XP](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/314503).

There are several solutions over there (I would have copy them to my answer, but they too long)
and I suggest that you give them a try.